# Cosine Rule Problem MathsWatch

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Question]

Did I do it completely wrong or is it just not giving me any marks?
I didn't use a calculator in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: $89-40=49=7^2$, not $49^2$.

Comment: Didn't gain any marks when changing it in the answer

Comment: Probably the machine doesn't understand your steps: try $b=\sqrt{8^2+5^2-2\times5\times8\times0.5}=7$. But your reasoning is sound, apart from that slip and the fact it should be $b$, rather than $c$.

Comment: The website isn't having it but thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it as follows: $$\begin{align}c^2&=8^2+5^2-(2\times5\times8\times0.5)\\&=64+25-40\\&=89-40\\&=49=7^2\\\implies c&=\sqrt{7^2}=7\end{align}$$

Perhaps the computer wanted to see "$c=7$" as the final line.

Comment: The computer asking for $b$ not $c$